# How to find the perimeter of a 30 60 90 Triangle?

Tags: geometry

[image]

A $24$

B $25$

C $28 $

D $30$

E $36$

So far I have tried $A+B+C$ to find the perimeter. However my efforts were in vain for I keep on getting 28 as my answer. I have tried $6\sqrt 3 + 6 + 12=28$ Although the answer is $30$

Comment: This is a square of side 6, from which an equilateral triangle of side 6 has been removed. Can you do it now?

Comment: Why is there no 30-60-90 triangle in your figure?

Comment: This was a very old question I do not remember I would have to find the original problem wherever it lay.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The triangle cut from the figure is equilateral, because it's interior angles must all be $60^\circ$.  Why? because $90^\circ - 30^\circ = 60^\circ$ for each of the adjecent lower angles. The sum of the measures of a triangle is $180^\circ$, so the remaining "top" angle must be $180 - 60 - 60 = 60^\circ$, too.

The side of the equilateral triangle (base) is known to be $6$, because the given figure is a square (missing bottom side) with side lengths all $6$. Since it's an equilateral triangle, the other two sides are length $6$ as well. (For an equilateral triangle: side = side = side, angle = angle = angle.)

The perimeter of the ***equilateral triangle*** (if we "added" the missing base) is 3 times the length of one of its sides: $$3 \times 6 = 18.$$

***The permimeter of the given figure***, as drawn, is $$5 \times 6 = 30$$ since all *five* edges are of length $6$:

- *three* are the 6-unit edges of a $6 \times 6$ "square-with-missing-side," and
- *two* are the 6-unit edges of an "equilateral-triangle-with-missing-side"

  So $3 \times 6 + 2 \times 6 = 5 \times 6 = 30:\;$ this matches choice $(D)$.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Do you see the equilateral triangle in the figure?

Comment: yes i do it is there

Comment: Its base is the same length as the upper line of this figure: 6. Since it is equilateral, the two unlabeled sides are also size 6.

Comment: Therefore the answer is $30$ because you add all the sides together because it is a square correct?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: er sort of. There are 5 sides and they all have length 6.